# How to determine if the device is an android tablet or an android TV

Tags: android-layout, android, android-tv

Is there a way to determine if the device is an android tablet or a TV? I know we could determine it using layout bins but then again tablets come in different sizes now a days. According to my knowledge TV UI is using 960dp layouts? at the same time there are tablets that use 960dp layouts as well. so is there a way of properly outline the two devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google published a nice check for that.

```
UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);
if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
    Log.d("TV", "Running on a TV Device")
} else {
    Log.d("TV", "Running on a non-TV Device")
}
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html)

Comment: Cool this looks interesing! I shall try this!

Comment: @PavelGP can you add some more details? Example set-top boxes that this does not work for?

Comment: @Rolfツ Yes, OpenBox A5, I work with this STB and this box behaves like android tablet: ui mode NORMAL. Think that some other simple STBs don't support UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION. Also their firmware doesn't support developer mode so I can't debug my app on this device:) I develop and debug on Nexus Player and then just check that OpenBox behaves in right way. To understand that the app runs on the OpenBox I use hack, I check battery level it always equals zero, it's bad but it works.

Comment: Another manufacturer implementing Android the wrong way... :(